# Python 3.6.2 from urllib.request import urlopen

Tags: python-3.x

This is a script that I want to start to use. I have seen this as a working version on a few location. Any one has an idea why this will not execute on my mac system. I am open to all ideas to solve this issue.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
print(html.read())
```

I get this as the output when executed.

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
====== RESTART: /Users/John/Documents/python_function_john/scraping.py ======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python_function_john/scraping.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "/Users/John/Documents/datetime.py", line 4
    print a.time()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Print is a function in python3. So try print(a.time())

Comment: Thank you, I found this was a script that I wrote some time ago was sitting in my documents folder, once I deleted the file the errors are reduced. Changed the code and it works thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is better that you install [Anaconda](http://www.anaconda.com); this application installs some `Python` package on your computer. Then write following line in `Conda Prompt`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge requests
```

After all, use `Spyder` application which has been installed with Anaconda.